# No se me redireccionan las rutas

Tags: laravel-5, redirección

Realice esta controller en laravel:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateUsersRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUsersRequest;
use App\Models\Users;
use App\Models\Roles;
use App\Repositories\UsersRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Flash;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

use App\Classes\LockSession;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;


class UsersController extends AppBaseController
{
    /** @var  UsersRepository */
    private $usersRepository;

    public function __construct(UsersRepository $usersRepo)
    {

        $this->middleware('lock');

        $this->middleware('noGoBack');
        $this->usersRepository = $usersRepo;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the Users.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */

    public function index()
    {
        $libros = Users::all();

        return view('users.index')->with('users', $libros);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new Users.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = Roles::all();

        return view('users.crear_usuario')->with('roles', $roles);
        //return view('users.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created Users in storage.
     *
     * @param CreateUsersRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $input['password'] = bcrypt($request->input('password'));

        if($request->hasFile($request->input('avatar'))){
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = $request->input('name') . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/uploads/avatars/'. $filename));

            $input['avatar'] = $filename;
        } else{
            $input['avatar'] = 'default.png';
        }

        $users = $this->usersRepository->create($input);

        $users->assign($request->input('rol'));

        Flash::success('El usuario se registro exitosamente');

        return redirect(route('users.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified Users.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $users = $this->usersRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($users)) {
            Flash::error('Users not found');

            return redirect(route('users.index'));
        }

        return view('users.show')->with('users', $users);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified Users.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $users = $this->usersRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($users)) {
            Flash::error('Users not found');

            return redirect(route('users.index'));
        }

        return view('users.edit')->with('users', $users);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified Users in storage.
     *
     * @param  int              $id
     * @param UpdateUsersRequest $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id, UpdateUsersRequest $request)
    {
        $users = $this->usersRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($users)) {
            Flash::error('Users not found');

            return redirect(route('users.index'));
        }

        $users = $this->usersRepository->update($request->all(), $id);

        Flash::success('Users updated successfully.');

        return redirect(route('users.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified Users from storage.
     *
     * @param  int $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = $this->usersRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

        if (empty($users)) {
            Flash::error('Usuario no encontrado');

            return redirect(route('users.index'));
        }

        $this->usersRepository->delete($id);

        Flash::success('Users deleted successfully.');

        return redirect(route('users.index'));
    }

    //Bloquea la session
    public function lock(){
        $token = Auth::user()->lockToken;
        $locked = Cache::remember('session_lock', 1000, function(){
            return [];
        });
        if(array_key_exists($token, $locked) === false){
            $locked[$token] = back()->getTargetUrl();
        }
        Cache::forever('session_lock', $locked);

        return redirect()->route('locked');
    }

    //Muestra la página de bloqueo
    public function locked(Request $request){
        //Solo puede acceder a esta página se se blokea primero
        if(!LockSession::isLocked()){
            return back();
        }
        return view('users.bloqueo');
    }

    //Verifica si puede desbloquear la sesion con los datos pasados por el request

    public function locked_check(Request $request){

        $email = Auth::user()->name;

        if(LockSession::isLocked() && Auth::attempt([
                'name' => $email,
                'password' => $request->get('password')
            ]))
        {
            $to = LockSession::unlock();

            return redirect($to);

        } elseif(LockSession::isLocked()){

            return redirect()->route('locked')->with('errors', collect(['password' => 'Sus credenciales son incorrectas']));

        }
        return redirect()->route('locked');
    }


}
```

Esta son mis rutas asociadas al problema:

```
Route::post('/bloquea', 'UsersController@lock')->name('auth_lock');

    Route::get('/bloqueado', 'UsersController@locked')->name('locked');

    Route::post('/chaquear_bloquedo', 'UsersController@locked_check')->name('locked_check');
```

Pero la funcion cuando llega al punto de la redirección: `return redirect()->route('locked');` el navegador me lanza este error:

```
Esta página no funciona
La página localhost te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.
Borrar las cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Le ha sucedido este problema?? como lo han podido resolver??

Comment: muestra la ruta a la que quieres redirigir.Lo que pasa para que funciones ese route , la ruta tiene que tener un name, Ejemplo: `Route::get('/ruta','NombreController@vistaRetrono')->name('ruta');`

Comment: Está redirigiendo infinitas veces, cae en una página que evalúa la redirección nuevamente. Revisa el criterio para hacer la redirección.

Comment: la ruta a la que quiero redirigirme es una que almacene en la cache

Comment: es esta: http://localhost/productos_ventas2/public/home

Comment: Si puedes pon las rutas para verificar una cosa.

Comment: ya estan puestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que pude apreciar tu problema de redirección es que entra en un ciclo infinito, ya que defines el middleware **lock** para todas tus acciones, por tanto la misma acción **login_check** es llamada continuamente y ejecutada la última línea. Las 2 posibles soluciones son excluir principalmente esta acción del middleware o remover la línea del middleware en el constructor de tu controladora y en el archivo de tus rutas incluirselo. Te dejo el primer caso a continuación:

```
public function __construct(UsersRepository $usersRepo)
{
    $this->middleware('lock')->except([
        'lock',
        'locked',
        'locked_check'
    ]);

    $this->middleware('noGoBack');
    $this->usersRepository = $usersRepo;
}
```

Espero que funcione !!!